# Besides Chhinnamasta and Ketu, are there any other headless figures?

Tags: gods, body

[Chhinnamasta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhinnamasta) is one goddess who is depicted as headless. Some forms of Ketu also show him without a head.

Are there any other deities or other figures in Hinduism who have no head? If there are, what is the story behind them?

Comment: ketu is not a deity, ketu is a graha, a shakti form at best...

Comment: @blue_ego - fair enough. I will change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The husband of the form Maa Chinnamasta is Bhagawan Chinnamastaka Shiva. Who is also headless as the name itself is suggesting. Also known as "Kabandha" also means headless.

**Shiva Purana in 3.16** gives Dash Avatar of Shiva and Shakti.:

> *3.16 Dash Avatar (10 Incarnations of Shiva) Describing about the ten incarnations and their corresponding power (Shakti), Sutji said- The first incarnation of lord Shiva was as Mahakal and his Shakti was called Mahakali. Lord Shiva took his second incarnation as Tar and his Shakti was called 'Tara'. The third incarnation of Lord Shiva was as Bhuvaneshwar and his Shakti was called 'Bhuvaneshwari'. Lord Shiva took his fourth incarnation as 'Shodash' who was also known as 'Srividdyesh' and his Shakti was called 'Shodashi' or 'Shri'. Lord Shiva took his fifth incarnation as Bhairav and his Shakti was called 'Bhairavi'. **The sixth incarnation of Lord Shiva is famous as 'Chhinamastak' and his Shakti by the name of 'Chhinamasta.** Lord Shiva took his seventh incarnation as 'Dhoomvan' and his Shakti was known as 'Dhoomvati. The eighth incarnation was as Baglamukh and his Shakti as Baglamukhi. The nineth incarnation of lord Shiva became famous as Matang and his Shakti as 'Matangi'. Lord Shiva took his tenth incarnation as 'Kamal' and his Shakti as Kamala. If these ten incarnation of Shiva are worshipped along with his ten Mahavidyas then a man attains salvation.*

I hope this clarifies your queries.